# Reviewing admin decision from a diamond moderator

Tags: discussion

This is unfair to me. Twice now @Ikegame has had his comments removed for trolling my question. So I edited the question itself -- sick of taking it to chat -- to address the very comments he keeps posting on the question. I had previously addressed those comments in chat, and on the question's comments. However, it's not fair to have a concern in a comment, and no response by the author.

So I responded. Not just did I respond, I responded with direct quotes. This has since become somewhat adversarial, but I'd like the ability to either

- Respond to him publicly in comments without having them purged.
- Respond to him in the question with direct sources.
- Not permit him to comment on my question.

This is pathetic that I can't quote someone in the question because it makes them look like a fool.

Anyway [this is the admin edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33285874/revisions), what's wrong with this? I'm being very exact and using quotes and examples that were provided to address the concerns being brought up in other biased answers and by the authors of the answers.

Comment: Adding irrelevant garbage to your question/answer is *never* the right choice.

Comment: You've been told, numerous times - at least 2 that I can see on that question - what the right answer is.  Take it to chat if you want to discuss things.  Editing the answer with comment responses is inappropriate.

Comment: The inclusion of [repeated] personal insults using offensive language that is directed at other users is also completely out of line.

Comment: Apart from all the meta noise isn't this just a case of [Someone is wrong on the internet](https://xkcd.com/386/) between everybody involved?

Comment: This reminds me of that one time I suggested someone use ROT13 for encryption.

Comment: This reminds me of that one time I saw a youtube video of two kids fighting on COD @Will

Comment: Don't have arguments on the (any) site. It never works out.

Comment: Now, the moderator is the culprit... I thought "the butler did it" was always the answer.

Comment: So many gold tags both of you...... you worry a simple user like me that tries to help out...

Answer (score 39):

First, Brad Larson is an awesome member of the moderation team with a past history that is basically infallible.

I think that the action taken inside of your comment line was appropriate. Directly insulting another user with an f bomb is way over the top regardless of circumstance, especially at Stack Overflow where we are supposed to be content oriented.

I think that the edit by the moderator in the answer was also appropriate for the simple reason that it was directed again at a single user and not at content. Instead of having the entire line directed at a single user, if it had been directed at the content used or issue raised, then that could have remained. That it was not content based and instead targeted at a user is why it was removed. I would assume that if you were to edit in the content targeted specifically at the issue raised without including the user or bias it would not be removed. In fact, this happens rather often where a point is made in comments, and then an answer is edited to approach the content of the issue (and not the user who raised the issue).

In review, I agree with Brad Larson. I also believe there are steps you can take to still address this issue in your answer without directly insulting another user.

Comment: I don't think expressing such a conditionless loyalty would be really constructive, especially not from the community building viewpoint. The community shouldn't be a herd following a leader conditionlessly, it should be a community of free spirits following common goals.

Comment: @peterh - It isn't without condition. It is from seeing this moderator in action for 4 years getting it right day in and day out. It was earned.

Comment: [Editor's note: peterh finds TravisJ's words ingratiating and expressed this rudely.]

Answer (score 25):

To address your question of "what's wrong with this", the problem is not with adding additional information to your question as requested in the comments. The problem is with the pointed phrasing you used, e.g. "that's his problem", "after being pestered by", "his X", "he did Y", *et cetera*.

Questions and answers on this site should be, for all intents and purposes, anonymous, in that they're made largely to the community, if not the public domain. It shouldn't matter who posted the question, the comment, or the answer in any single case, only that those things were posted.

Instead of simply adding additional information, you went out of your way to belabor the fact that you find Ikegame's comments annoying/unnecessary, and you did it in about a dozen different ways. That is not useful to the site, it's not useful to future readers, and it's therefore not appropriate content.

Chat exists for such extraneous discussions, so if you're truly getting tired of moving discussions there, then I would recommend trying to resolve any comment discussions sooner, or if all else fails, finding/writing a user script to hide comments by Ikegame on questions where you're the asker.

Comment: So then tell him to stop posting on the question, and I'll stop having to address him in the answer. After I've already addressed him in the question and he gets to post another comment, you're defeating the purpose.. I had already addressed his concerns in the chat, and on the question.

Comment: You could always be the mature one and simply move on... @EvanCarroll

Comment: If you address his concerns and he continues, why do you bang your head against it? There's a point where you can just shrug it off and go to another question, no?